# Apply Count formula in a Excel Row with conditions True/False

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have to apply a logical count formula on a column which contains some value. It contains identical and non-identical numbers.

What I want is a way to apply a formula to the next column which will lookup the whole column and decide on below condition:

whether A1=A2; if True, if A1=A3 and so on till it returns False (not equal value) then count all the true results in a row and reflect the value against the first cell.
Then if there was three match then it should reflect 3 against the first cell and the next two cells should be left blank. Below is the example column:

```
Numbers   No of Days

47.76   
-429.98 
-429.98 
-429.98 
-1328.98    
-1328.98    
-1328.98    
-833.32 
-643.7  
-1328.98    
-580.26 
-556.76 
-556.76 
-1181.78    
-1139.99    
-1124.49    
-1103.59    
-1103.59    
-1091.39    
-1048.94    
-1048.94    
-451.38 
-451.38 
-321    
-321    
438.5   
477.5   
698.76  
795.93  
795.93  
804.83
```

What I want should be like below after formula:

```
Numbers   No of Days
47.76     1
-429.98   3
-429.98 
-429.98 
-1328.98  3
-1328.98    
-1328.98    
-833.32   1
-643.7    1
-1328.98  1
-580.26   1
-556.76   2
-556.76 
-1181.78  1
-1139.99  1
-1124.49  1
-1103.59  2
-1103.59    
-1091.39  1
-1048.94  2
-1048.94    
-451.38   2
-451.38 
-321      2
-321    
438.5     1
477.5     1
698.76    1
795.93    2
795.93  
804.83    1
```

Please help guys as whatever I tried has failed here. Need some excel experts to share some advise or a resolve.

Comment: Please post what you tried and what the errors were.

Answer (score 2):

In Cell B2 use `=IF(A2=A1,"",MATCH(0,--(A2=$A2:$A$50),0)-1)` entered using **ctrl+shift+enter**

The if statement checks to see if the number is the same as the one above it and if it is it leaves the cell blank.

Inside the match statement --(A2=$A2:$A$50) returns an array of 0s (if the cell doesn't match A2) or 1s (if it does match).  The match statement finds the first 0 in the array (the first number that doesn't match).  Since this returns the place in the array that starts at the current row it will give the number of rows that match+1.  We just need to subtract that 1 to get the number we need.